# Presentation matrix for module in terms of other presentation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $A$ and $B$ be right $R$-modules. Suppose that the following two sequences are exact:
$$
R^u\stackrel{Q}{\to} R^s\stackrel{\pi}{\to}A\to 0 \\ R^r\stackrel{f}{\to} A\to B\to 0
$$
and there exists a map $P:R^r\to R^s$ such that $\pi\circ P=f$. Also $P$ and $Q$ can be considered to be matrices of appropriate dimensions (and are multiplied on the right. That they are right-modules and matrix multiplication is on the right is not super important to the problem, but I'm too tired to convert it to left)

(Sorry, I don't know how to draw commutative diagrams here, but I've included a picture of the [commutative diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6O13.png).)

Question: What is a presentation matrix for $B$?

Secondary Question: Is there a way to get a formula for $f$?

Known: $A=R^s/R^uQ$, that is $Q$ is a presentation matrix for $A$, and $B=A/f(R^r)=A/\pi(R^rP)$. Combining these two facts, we obtain $$B=\dfrac{R^s/R^uQ}{\pi(R^rP)}$$

My suspicion is that $B$ is presented by the block matrix 
$$V=\begin{pmatrix}
P\\
Q
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $R^r\oplus R^u\stackrel{V}{\to}R^s\to B\to 0$ is exact.
My reasoning is, $B=A/f(R^r)$ and $f=\pi\circ P$. $A$ has $s$ generators and $u$ relations with presentation matrix $Q$. So $B$ has at most $s$ generators. Given $x\in R^r$, $xP$ gives $f(x)$ in terms of the generators of $A$. So $R^rP$ gives $r$ relations for $B$. But these aren't enough, they can be further simplified with the relations $R^uQ$. So $B=R^s/(R^rP)/(R^uQ)=R^s/(R^{r+u}V)$. I don't know if this makes any sense. I'm feeling very stupid right now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}\DeclareMathOperator{\cok}{cok}\newcommand{\psm}[2]{\left[\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}\right]}$Your suspicion is correct, that's $V$ is the representation matrix of $B$.
This means that $\pi g:R^s\to B$ (with diagrammatic order composition) is the cokernel of $V$.
To prove this, consider the following commutative diagram with exact rows
\begin{CD}
R^u@>Q>>R^s@>\pi>>A@>>>\{0\}\\
@.@APAA@|\\
@.R^r@>>f>A@>>g>B@>>>\{0\}
\end{CD}
Then $\pi$ is the cokernel of $Q$ and $g$ is the cokernel of $f$.
Note that the cokernel of $V$ is the cointersection of cokernels of $P$ and $Q$, that's the diagonal of the right-handed square in the following commutative diagram (where both squares are pushout):
\begin{CD}
R^r@>P>>R^s@>\pi>>A\\
@VVV@VV\cok PV@VVgV\\
\{0\}@>>>\bullet@>>>B
\end{CD}
hence the assertion follows.

---

If you don't know this property of cokernels argue as follows.
Clearly, we have
$$\psm PQ\pi g=\psm{P\pi g}{Q\pi g}=\psm{fg}{Q\pi g}=0$$
for $fg=0$ because $g$ is the cokernel of $f$ (by exactness of bottom row) and $Q\pi=0$ by exactness of upper row.
On the other hand let $k:R^s\to Y$ such that
$$\psm PQk=0$$
that's $Pk=0$ and $Qk=0$.
From $Pk=0$ we get $k=(\cok P)u$ where $\cok P$ denote the cokernel of $P$, for some $u$ and $k=\pi v$ for some $v$, because $\pi$ is the cokernel of $Q$.
Since $(\cok P)u=k=\pi v$, by universal property of pushout, there exists one and only one morphism $h:B\to Y$ such that $v=gh$, hence $k=\pi gh$.

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much! I never knew that cokernels referred to maps as well as spaces. I'm learning so much category theory today. However, your interpretation of the block matrix (P \\ Q) is wrong. (x,y)(P \\ Q) is not (xP, yQ), but xP+yQ. the way you're interpreting it is as a map to R^s x R^s.

Comment: Glad to help you; my interpretation of $V $ is correct, but I write morphism composition in diagrammatic order.